# XML Schema force two attributes to be different

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, restriction

In my XML I have defined categories

```
<category id="3" parent-category-id="2">
    <name>Child category</name>
</category>
```

As you can see I have a category element, which can have a parent category defined.
Both attributes are defined in my XML Schema file:

```
<xs:attribute name="id" use="required" type="xs:string" />
<xs:attribute name="parent-category-id" use="optional" type="xs:string" />
```

I also have keys and keyrefs set in my XSD file. Now I wonder if this is possible to somehow restrict parent-category-id, so that it cannot point to self id.
For example I can write:

```
<category id="3" parent-category-id="3">
```

and such XML file will still validate, althought it shouldn't.

My keys and keyrefs are:

```
<xs:key name="ID">
    <xs:selector xpath="categories/category" />
    <xs:field xpath="@id" />
</xs:key>

<xs:keyref name="PARENT_CATEGORY_ID_REF" refer="ID">
    <xs:selector xpath="categories/category" />
    <xs:field xpath="@parent-category-id" />
</xs:keyref>
```

It would be great, if I could add some kind of restriction, that would tell the validator that id cannot == parent-category-id.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an XSD validator that supports version 1.1, you can use an assert after the xs:attribute elements to enforce your restriction:

```
<xs:assert test="@id != @parent-category-id"/>
```

Personally I'm having trouble locating a validator that does support 1.1 though.  Version 1.0 does not support assert.